# Tensorflow model not updating the variables

Tags: python, tensorflow

Problem Summary:

The issue is that even after running this code for multiple epochs, the cost isn't reducing much ( I have tried this for a variety of starting_learning_rates ). The equation that I am trying to optimize is ((m * pow(length, u) * pow(start_y, t) + c) where length and start_y are the inputs and u,t,m and c are learn-able parameters. I was able to observe (my dataset is quite small) that length * sqrt(start_y) is almost a constant and thought that tensorflow would be able to better help me find the value of the variables

This is my tensorflow code, combined_vehicles is an array with 129 rows and 2 columns( 2 features ), combined_labels is an array corresponding to labels for each of the examples in combined_vehicles

```
u = tf.Variable(0.0,dtype = "float32")
t = tf.Variable(0.0,dtype = "float32")
c = tf.Variable(0.0,dtype = "float32")
m = tf.Variable(0.0,dtype = "float32")

length = tf.placeholder(dtype = "float32", shape = [combined_vehicles.shape[0],1], name="length")
start_y = tf.placeholder(dtype = "float32", shape = [combined_vehicles.shape[0],1], name="start_y")
labels = tf.placeholder(dtype = "float32", shape = [combined_vehicles.shape[0],1], name = "labels")

output = tf.add(tf.multiply(tf.multiply(tf.pow(length, u), tf.pow(start_y, t)), m), c)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = output, labels = labels))
global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False, name = 'global_step')

start_learning_rate = 0.0001
decay_steps = 100
learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(start_learning_rate, global_step, decay_steps, 0.1, staircase=True )

result_output = output > 0.5
result_label = combined_labels > 0.5
correct_prediction = tf.equal( result_output, result_label )
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean( tf.cast( correct_prediction, "float" ) )

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost, global_step=global_step)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    epochs = 100
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(epochs):
        _,cost_estimate = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict = {length: combined_vehicles[:,0].reshape([combined_vehicles.shape[0],1]), start_y:combined_vehicles[:,1].reshape([combined_vehicles.shape[0],1]), labels: combined_labels})
    total_accuracy = accuracy.eval({length: combined_vehicles[:,0].reshape([combined_vehicles.shape[0],1]), start_y:combined_vehicles[:,1].reshape([combined_vehicles.shape[0],1]), labels: combined_labels})
```

Comment: Can you try setting different starting values? 0 might be killing your gradients

Comment: You might wanna draw them from a random distribution of some sort

Comment: +1 to looking into initialization. Also, for testing purposes, since your model is a small formula with a few parameters, if you real data is small, you can train the model with arbitrarily large synthetic data (choosing some `u`, `t`, `m` and `c`, plus noise if you want) and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: So I tried using random initialization and even that isn't helping reduce the cost.